# C# how to print out an array of PictureBox in multiple pages

Tags: c#, printing, graphics, picturebox

using C#, I wrote the below code to print out images in an array (size = totalToPrint) of Picturebox pictureBoxArr[] each in size of 100x100 pixel. I want to print them vertically with the 20-pixel distance between them heightDistanceBetweenImages the problem is that it only prints on 1 page (say letter size) no matter how many images ( then it only prints 8 images and dismisses the rest). How can I solve this problem, and print it on multiple pages?

```
    int totalToPrint;
    int xFirstAncorPoint = 100;
    int yFirstAncorPoint = 100;
    int ImagSize = 100; // Squre of 100x100 pixel 
    int heightDistanceBetweenImages = 20;



  PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument pDoc = new PrintDocument();
        pDoc.PrintPage += PrintPicture;
        pd.Document = pDoc;
        if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pDoc.Print();
        }

    }


    public void PrintPicture(Object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(ImagSize , totalToPrint * (ImagSize + heightDistanceBetweenImages));
        for (int i = 0; i < totalToPrint; i++)
        {
            pictureBoxArr[i].DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, i * (heightDistanceBetweenImages + ImagSize), pictureBoxArr[0].Width, pictureBoxArr[0].Height));
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp1, xFirstAncorPoint, yFirstAncorPoint);
        bmp1.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are about half way there. [PrintDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) would be your future reference.

The `PrintPage` gives you more than just a drawing space; it also has your page bounds, page margins, etc. It also has `HasMorePages` property that you set if you need to print more pages. This property defaults to false, so you were only printing 1 page. Also if anything is outside the bounds of the page, it would not print that. With a little change here and there, you would end up with something like this.

```
// using queue to manage images to print
Queue<Image> printImages = new Queue<Image>();
int totalToPrint;
int xFirstAncorPoint = 100;
int yFirstAncorPoint = 100;
int ImagSize = 100; // Squre of 100x100 pixel 
int heightDistanceBetweenImages = 20;

private void btnPrintTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
    PrintDocument pDoc = new PrintDocument();
    pDoc.PrintPage += PrintPicture;
    pd.Document = pDoc;
    if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        // add image references to printImages queue.
        for (int i = 0; i < pictureBoxArr.Length; i++) {
            printImages.Enqueue(pictureBoxArr[i].Image);
        }
        pDoc.Print();
    }
}

private void PrintPicture(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
    int boundsHeight = e.MarginBounds.Height;       // Get height of bounds that we are expected to print in.
    int currentHeight = yFirstAncorPoint;

    while (currentHeight <= boundsHeight && printImages.Count > 0) {
        var nextImg = printImages.Peek();
        int nextElementHeight = nextImg.Height + heightDistanceBetweenImages;

        if (nextElementHeight + currentHeight <= boundsHeight) {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(nextImg, new PointF(xFirstAncorPoint, currentHeight + heightDistanceBetweenImages));

            printImages.Dequeue();
        }

        currentHeight += nextElementHeight;
    }

    // how we specify if we may have more pages to print
    e.HasMorePages = printImages.Count > 0;
}
```

Hopefully this gets you on the right path and with some minor tweaks for your code, you will have what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I like the "Queue" you used, it works now.

Comment: I just used  made a bit change, since not all the picrureboxes includes Image ( I has just pre declate array of 30 / max that I might have and fill them with image, my be I should change that to list or queue make it nicer, any way I used TotalToPrint instead of Arr.Lenght as bellow and it wortks perfect      // add image references to printImages queue.
                for (int i = 0; i < totalToPrint; i++)
                {
                    printImages.Enqueue(pictureBoxArr[i].Image);
                }